# A Rank comparison test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, ranking

Is there a test that one can use to perform rank comparison tests.

In other words if I have 2 variables (say income in all 10 regions of country X; and, income in all 10 regions of country Y) and I want to know if the ranking pattern in one variable is similar to that of the other.

Comment: Please tell us what a "ranking pattern" is and how we might possibly compare regions between two different countries with it!

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find 
information on how to do this in the **My Account** 
section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Answer (score 0):

What comes to mind is Spearman rank correlation analysis, which will generate income ranks within each country, and then determine if the ranks are associated (correlated).  The default test typically determines if correlation, $r_S$, is equal to zero (null hypothesis) or not equal to zero (alternative hypothesis).  Recall, correlation $r_S$ has range [-1,1] so the association between income across countries can be positive, $r_S>0$, or negative, $r_S<0$.  For the computational run, just specify the two variables to use and run Spearman with the original income values, the software will automatically do the within-country ranking internally.